# Python 2-D ARRAY CONFUSION

Tags: python, arrays

I don't understand why the entire 2D is getting populated while I am trying ton access only the diagonal elements:

```
a = [[0]*3]*3
print("INIT ARRAY: ", a)

for i in range(3):
    a[i][i] = 1 

print("FINAL ARRAY:", a)
```

Answer :

```
INIT ARRAY:  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
FINAL ARRAY: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: `[[]]*3` creates one list of lists where 3 of the sublists are the same reference. Try: `[[0] * 3 for _ in range(3)]`

Answer (score 1):

**REASON**
This is happening because all three arrays (or list) are stored in the same memory (RAM) location when you multiply them.
You can find the memory location of the object in python by using

```
id(object_name)
```

Now try this code to understand the reason.

```
a = [[0]*3]*3
print("INIT ARRAY: ", a)

print(id(a[0][0]))
print(id(a[1][0]))
print(id(a[2][0]))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
INIT ARRAY:  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
140394015555792  #all three lists have same memory location.
140394015555792
140394015555792
```

That is why when you are modifying only diagonal elements other elements also get modified.

**SOLUTION**

```
a = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] # This list elements have memory location

print("Initial ARRAY", a)

for i in range(3):
    a[i][i] = 1

print("Final ARRAY", a)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Initial ARRAY [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
Final ARRAY [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

**SOLUTION**

```
a = []

# Method you can use to generate array with different memory locations.
for i in range(3):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        a[i].append(0)

print("INIT ARRAY: ", a)

for i in range(3):
    a[i][i] = 1

print("FINAL ARRAY:", a)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
INIT ARRAY:  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
FINAL ARRAY: [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```